# InfluxDB write points with same timestamp but different measurement

Tags: time-series, influxdb, influxdb-python

Requirement:
I want to create an influxDB database to store time-series data from multiple sensors reporting temperatures from different locations.

Problem: 
When I write points to the database with same timestamp but different tags (example : location) and field (temperature) value , influx overwrites both tags and fields values with the latest timestamp

I followed the documentation available on their website and they show a sample db with above requirement but am not able find the schema used.

[Example Table with duplicate timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg0aG.png)

Additional Information :
Sample Input :

```
json_body_1 = [
{
    "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
    "tags": {
        "host": "server02",
        "region": "us-west"
    },
    "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
    "fields": {
        "Float_value": 0.7,
        "Int_value": 6,
        "String_value": "Text",
        "Bool_value": False
    }
},
{
    "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
    "tags": {
        "host": "server01",
        "region": "us-west"
    },
    "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
    "fields": {
        "Float_value": 1.0,
        "Int_value": 2,
        "String_value": "Text",
        "Bool_value": False
    }
}]
```

I used the example given in official documentation , still instead of 2 records , I get only one. Please note host tag is different which should ideally make each point unique.

[Documentation](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#tutorials-basic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I too faced the same issue and now I come to the solution. :)

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

client = InfluxDBClient(host='host name', port=8086, database='test_db',username='writer', password=Config.INFLUXDB_WRITE_PWD)

points = [{
    "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
    "tags": {
        "host": "server02",
        "region": "us-west"
    },
    "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
    "fields": {
        "Float_value": 0.7,
        "Int_value": 6,
        "String_value": "Text",
        "Bool_value": False
    }
},
{
    "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
    "tags": {
        "host": "server01",
        "region": "us-west"
    },
    "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
    "fields": {
        "Float_value": 1.0,
        "Int_value": 2,
        "String_value": "Text",
        "Bool_value": False
    }
}]

status = client.write_points(json_body_1, database='test_db', batch_size=10000, protocol='json')
```

Here is the output

```
> select * from cpu_load_short;
name: cpu_load_short
time                Bool_value Float_value Int_value String_value host     region
----                ---------- ----------- --------- ------------ ----     ------
1257894000000000000 false      1           2         Text         server01 us-west
1257894000000000000 false      0.7         6         Text         server02 us-west
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing different ?

Comment: is it the case that having different tags will create a new entry? looks like the only difference in the post

Comment: Having different tags could let you insert same value with same timestamp. Having same value and timestamp, InfluxDb will update the old one, so different tags will do the trick.